# Hash Key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to initialise the `hash pair` and then look for the key using `has.key` in the hash pair value. I have given the condition see below:

```
if seen.has.key?(var)
    <Execute Condition>
```

Could you shed lights on it how this actually works? I have tried looking around but still confuses me. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`seen={}` assigns an empty hashmap to the variable `seen` and `has.key` calls the method `key` on the object `has`. Assuming that `has` is a hashmap, `key` is a method that takes a value as its argument and returns the key that maps to the given value in the hashmap.

`seen.has.key?(var)` calls the `has` method on `seen` and then calls the `key?` method with the argument `var` on the result of that. Since hashmap objects don't have a `has` method, this will cause a `NoMethodError`.